# How to write shell script which handles interactive inputs?

Tags: shell, unix, expect

I have a command which takes 2 arguments.

When I run the command manually, I do this way:

```
cmd -i xyz.dat  
hit enter 
enter password in the prompt 
hit enter
confirm password
```

My script needs to do the above operations without expecting user to enter password. I can hardcode the passwords in the file, but need a way to run this command successfully when I execute the shell script.

As on Feb 7th,
I have expect installed on my AIX. When I type expect at the command prompt, the prompt changes to expect 1.1>  OS is 64 bit AIX

I have followed the instructions mentioned in the below comment, but I keep getting error - could not execute the command; no such file or directory"? I am able to manually run this command from same directory I am running the script. Besides that I have given the complete path of the command and the 
file.

I am pasting another program I tried to su with root password as below: i get the same error message when I run the test program. I doubt if this is something related to quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash
set timeout 20
spawn "su"
expect "Password:" { send:"temp123\r" }
interact
```

Can someone please help me fix this error?

Comment: If you get 'no such file or directory' errors, it means that `expect` is not installed on your system. This is not wholly unexpected (if you'll excuse the pun).  Installing `expect` also, AFAICR, requires Tcl (or, at least, `expect` is based on Tcl/Tk, so you will end up with Tcl technology when you install `expect`).  But you may well be able to install someone else's precompiled version with an appropriate command — the details of which depend intensely on which brand of Unix you're using, and if it is Linux, which distro (different distros have different systems for installing software).

Comment: I have expect installed.

Comment: OK; it's good to document that you have `expect` installed and able to run.  Now, where is the `cmd` you are running installed?  Is it on your PATH?  (It must be when you run it directly, so I don't expect that to be a problem.)  You might need to check whether `expect`'s `spawn` command does a path-based search.  I would be surprised if it did not, but funnier things have been known (and it would explain the error).

Comment: There's a manual for [`expect`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/) version 5.31.  The information on `spawn` is not specific about 'searching PATH', but I think it is reasonable to assume it does. You're giving conflicting platform information. You say "I have expect installed on my linux. … OS is 64 bit AIX". Are you running on Linux or AIX (or both)? And where are you having the problem?

Comment: I have linux machine and I tried the code there. I have an AIX server which I am connecting through putty. I checked expect is installed on both.

Comment: If the expect's spawn command is doing path based search, I have provided complete path of the command. It still complains about the path. So, any thoughts on this?

Comment: The manual page I referenced earlier says: ***spawn*** _[args] program [args]_  creates a new process running _program args._ From that, I deduce you should be using: `spawn "cmd" "-i" "xyz.dat"` even though the other answer suggests otherwise.  I suspect that most of those quotes are optional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70497/discussion-between-smiley-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to use expect.  [Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/) is a page with some examples.

So for your command you would want something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

spawn "cmd -i xyz.dat"

expect "<your password prompt" { send "<your password>\r" }
expect "<your password confirmation prompt" { send "<your password>\r" }

interact
```